# How to store settings in Android Application?

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey, delphi-10.3-rio

I want my application to save/load settings (and preserve them when "upgrading"/installing a new version).
Which component can I use for this? Registry wont be available I guess :-)

UPDATE: Settings like a string, a number or a boolean. Application settings, the user "manages" inside the app.

Comment: what type of settings are you talking about ?

Comment: Settings like a string, a number or a boolean. Application settings, the user "manages" inside the app.

Comment: You can save settings just like in Windows apps by using TStringlist.SavetoFile and use name=value pairs.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Android equivalent of Registry are [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences)

You can easily get to the application private instance of `SharedPreferences` through `TAndroidHelper.PrivatePreferences` class function.

For retrieving stored settings you can then use following methods:

```
  JSharedPreferences = interface(IJavaInstance)
    ['{E44179D1-B961-4316-A8B0-45B52A482FA7}']
    function &contains(key: JString): Boolean; cdecl;
    function edit: JSharedPreferences_Editor; cdecl;
    function getAll: JMap; cdecl;
    function getBoolean(key: JString; defValue: Boolean): Boolean; cdecl;
    function getFloat(key: JString; defValue: Single): Single; cdecl;
    function getInt(key: JString; defValue: Integer): Integer; cdecl;
    function getLong(key: JString; defValue: Int64): Int64; cdecl;
    function getString(key: JString; defValue: JString): JString; cdecl;
    function getStringSet(key: JString; defValues: JSet): JSet; cdecl;
    procedure registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(listener: JSharedPreferences_OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener); cdecl;
    procedure unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(listener: JSharedPreferences_OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener); cdecl;
  end;
```

In order to save settings you need to call `edit` method on preference instance and then you can use following editor methods to store data:

```
  JSharedPreferences_Editor = interface(IJavaInstance)
    ['{A162AACF-DD6D-466E-838B-363E6B092CA4}']
    procedure apply; cdecl;
    function clear: JSharedPreferences_Editor; cdecl;
    function commit: Boolean; cdecl;
    function putBoolean(key: JString; value: Boolean): JSharedPreferences_Editor; cdecl;
    function putFloat(key: JString; value: Single): JSharedPreferences_Editor; cdecl;
    function putInt(key: JString; value: Integer): JSharedPreferences_Editor; cdecl;
    function putLong(key: JString; value: Int64): JSharedPreferences_Editor; cdecl;
    function putString(key: JString; value: JString): JSharedPreferences_Editor; cdecl;
    function putStringSet(key: JString; values: JSet): JSharedPreferences_Editor; cdecl;
    function remove(key: JString): JSharedPreferences_Editor; cdecl;
  end;
```

After you are done with modifying settings, you need to call `apply` or `commit` on editor. The only difference between the two is that apply just stores the data, and commit returns whether operation was successful or not.

Following is simple example that stores and reads boolean data.

Save data:

```
uses
  AndroidApi.Helpers,
  Androidapi.JNI.GraphicsContentViewText,


var
  Pref: JSharedPreferences;
  PrefEditor: JSharedPreferences_Editor;
  Success: Boolean;
begin
  Pref := TAndroidHelper.PrivatePreferences;

  PrefEditor := Pref.edit;
  PrefEditor.putBoolean(StringToJString('key'), True);
  PrefEditor.apply;
  // or
  Success := PrefEditor.commit;
end;
```

Load data:

```
var
  Pref: JSharedPreferences;
  Value: Boolean;
begin
  Pref := TAndroidHelper.PrivatePreferences;     
  Value := Pref.getBoolean(StringToJString('key'), False);
end;
```

You can also use any custom format (like Ini file) to save data in application local storage.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **SharedPreferences** to store your settings

Example: in **Java** As you didn't define in which language you are writing your Android application

```
public static SharedPreferences getPreferences(Context context) {
    String appName = context.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name);
    return context.getSharedPreferences(appName, MODE);
}

public static void clearSharedPreferenceFile(Context context) {
    getEditor(context).clear().apply();
}

public static SharedPreferences.Editor getEditor(Context context) {
    return getPreferences(context).edit();
}

public static void writeString(Context context, String key, String value) {
    getEditor(context).putString(key, value).apply();
}

public static String readString(Context context, String key) {
    return getPreferences(context).getString(key, "");
}

public static void writeInt(Context context, String key, int value) {
    getEditor(context).putInt(key, value).apply();
}

public static int readInt(Context context, String key) {
    return getPreferences(context).getInt(key, Integer.MIN_VALUE);
}
public static void writeBoolean(Context context, String key, boolean value) {
    getEditor(context).putBoolean(key, value).apply();
}

public static boolean readBoolean(Context context, String key) {
    return getPreferences(context).getBoolean(key, false);
}
```

Comment: "As you didn't define in which language you are writing your Android application" The tags are very clear to me: Delphi Firemonkey. Specifically, version 10.3.

Answer (score 1):

You can use SharedPreferences, File or Database to save your data